# What are the uses of svn copy?

Tags: svn, version-control

Example:

```
$ svn copy foo.txt bar.txt  
A    bar.txt
```

- When would you use this technique, and why?
- Will this command (taken from svn's "red book") creates a copy of `<foo.txt>` while preserving the history of it to be shared with `<bar.txt>`?
- If I'm changing `<bar.txt>`, what will happen to `<foo.txt>`?

What are the equivalents to this in other modern systems (Clearcase, Accurev, Perforce)?

Let me emphasize the point I'm searching for:
Is this kind of branching out on a file level?
What happens if you use it in the same branch, i.e. create a copy of a file and than start changing that new file. all in the same branch?
I understand that it is also used for tagging but what is interesting me is what to expect when performing `<svn copy>` on the file level.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Aside from branching/tagging, you can also use it when you split a file in two. In this case both new files will have history and you'll be able to look at the code before the split.

BTW: that's one of few features that SVN has, but Git doesn't (Git will try to guess origin of code after the fact, especially if you add `-C` to commands).

Comment: Nice, I've not seen that one before.

Comment: Apparently Git can do this - see Dustin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/335791/44390).

Comment: @mskfisher Git does that by guessing which files look similar (if you enable the `-C` option/config), not by storing explicit metadata about file's origin. If you modify too many lines then git won't be able to figure it out (to work around that I do two commits: one with unchanged file copy and second with changes I wanted to make, but that's not very elegant).

Answer (score 23):

> When would you use this technique, and why?

To create tags, and also to create branches, although usually you'd use it on a directory rather than a single file. A tag is a copy of one or more files, which you keep for convenience but never change again. A branch is a copy of one or more files, which then evolves separately from the original

> Will this command create a copy of `foo.txt` while preserving the history of it to be shared with `bar.txt`?

Not quite, `foo.txt`'s history will effectively be copied to the history of `bar.txt`, then an extra entry appears in the history of `bar.txt` indicating that it was copied from `foo.txt`, and thereafter they are independent. So the history up to the point of the copy is identical/shared.

> If I'm changing `bar.txt`, what will happen to `foo.txt`?

Nothing, they are completely separate. But you can later merge changes from one to the other.

Comment: I believe Copy will also be smart enough to efficiently store the history... if the file(s) have a long history, this saves significant space. Updates to the log will also be shared between files I believe.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's right. SVN loudly advertises that the file is a "logical" copy, but does not duplicate the contents of the file in the database. This claim would be nonsense if it didn't apply to the whole history, and tagging would be incredibly expensive in DB space. Which it isn't.

Answer (score 10):

This is a slightly unusual use, but I find that sometimes I have to divide a source file into two separate files - for example, if it contains two sets of unrelated functionality, and I use svn copy to do this.  I then modify both files and delete the inappropriate bits from each.  This way, both of the new files retain revision history for their relevant bits.

Answer (score 8):

> What are the equivalents to this in
>   other modern systems (Clearcase,
>   Accurev, Perforce)?

git will notice the file is the same on a plain copy and show it as a copy.

Comment: Please describe why you feel this is inaccurate so I can correct it and don't just vote down.

Answer (score 2):

I use this technique when I'm creating a new file, and I want to copy scaffolding (I currently use Perforce, but used to use Subversion).  Changing a copy will not effect the other file.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down - I've done this myself. It means that if you change the boilerplate (copyright notice and blah blah), then merging the change into whichever derived files need it is exactly the same operation as a normal trunk->branch merge.

Answer (score 1):

Branch is not a first-class citizen in Subversion, since it is "implemented" as a directory.

Hence, the `svn copy` allow to kind of branch of file within the same branch (directory). You can later merge back the copied file into the first. But **this is ill-suited for just one file**, as mentionned in [this thread](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-04/1062.shtml)

The equivalent in ClearCase would be a select rule like

```
element * .../myBranchForCopy/LATEST
element /myPath/myFile /main/myBranch/LATEST -mkbranch myBranchForCopy
```

However, in this view made for branching a file, you will only see one `foo.txt` at a time (either in the `myBranch`, or if it is checked-out, in the `myBranchForCopy`). There is no real "copy", it is the same element. Any merge would be between:

- `foo.txt@@/main/myBranch/myBranchForCopy/LATEST`
  and
- `foo.txt@@/main/myBranch/LATEST`

Answer (score 1):

`svn copy` came in handy after I inadvertantly deleted a file. See the [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873478/svn-cat-after-svn-del/2873724#2873724) to an accoring [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873478/svn-cat-after-svn-del) I have asked.