# svn cat after svn del

Tags: svn

I have inadvertently svn-deleted a file with `svn del --targets del.txt`. Now, I'd like to recover that file with `svn cat myPreciousFile.txt@4130 > myPreciousFile.txt`, but svn gives me a warning that myPreciousFile.txt *is not under version control*. A `svn cat -r 4130 myPreciousFile.txt > myPreciousFile.txt` didn't work, either.

Can someone please tell me how I'd go about recovering this file again?

**EDIT**

Ok, I have tried it with `svn merge`, but it still doesn't work. Here's what I did (file names altered to protect the guilty...):

```
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn diff -r 4250:4251 --summarize
D      file_one.tyb
D      file_two.tyb
D      myPreciousFile.txt
```

I interpret this output as "myPreciousFile was deleted in revision 4251".
So, I tried it with `svn merge`:

```
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn merge-c -4251 myPreciousFile.txt
```

And svn still warns me about myPreciousFile.txt not being under version control. (Same error message btw with `svn merge-c -4250 myPreciousFile.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not restore file with `cat`.

The proper way of doing this is `copy`

```
svn copy http://server/full/path/to/myPreciousFile.txt@4130 .
```

after that commit current directory. with this solution you will keep the complete history of changings of that file.

Answer (score 3):

```
svn merge -c -<revision where you deleted the file> .
```

So if the delete occurred during revision 4131, you would:

```
svn merge -c -4131 .
             ^ the negative on the revision is important
```

In response to the question edit:

You shouldn't specify the filename.  Just do `.` and your file will be restored.  Then `svn revert` the changes that you don't want back.

Comment: `svn merge` is the operation of applying some bunch of changesets (diffs) to the particular file. in this case you cannot use the command in the way you displayed.

Comment: @zerkms: you are not correct.  the command works exactly as typed in the tests i ran before posting my response.

Comment: @zerkms: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Comment: @Sean: --- Reverse-merging r28 into '.':
   C file.txt
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1

Comment: and documentation is talking about reverting **changes**. it said about how to **undo changes** of file.

Comment: @zerkms: a deletion is a change.

Comment: your most recent comment doesn't make grammatical sense so i am not sure what you are trying to say.  regardless, from the documentation that i linked: "One option is to use svn merge to apply revision 808 'in reverse.' (...) This would have the effect of re-adding real.c as a local modification. The file would be scheduled for addition, and after a commit, the file would again exist in HEAD."

Comment: @wds: i know :-) but documentation is talking about another kind of changes. anyway, as you can see it does not work for me.

Comment: I added another answer with demonstration that it doesn't work. you can comment there.

Comment: oops, my miss. i had to specify the revision at which file was deleted. sorry guys. everything is good.

Comment: anyway, my accepted answer is more correct, due to it keeps the previous history.

Comment: @zerkms: rolling back the delete will also keep the previous history. Both answers are correct.

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure why this is still in question.

Comment: hmmmmmm...... i was totally wrong :-S don't know why i thought that `merge` will not keep logs... `merge` is just a `get diff+apply diff` - how could it track the changes?

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can do a reverse merge to get your file back. I suspect that your command is failing because you also specified the specific file you want to merge, and that file isn't under source control anymore. I can see two options for how to recover it.

### Merge and revert

Reverse merge the whole commit, then revert the files you really did want to delete. Here's the example you gave:

```
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn diff -r 4250:4251 --summarize
D      file_one.tyb
D      file_two.tyb
D      myPreciousFile.txt
```

Do the reverse merge:

```
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn merge -c -4251
```

Then revert the two you really meant to delete:

```
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn revert file_one.tyb
f:\path\to\dev\dir> svn revert file_two.tyb
```

### Copy

Use the copy command suggested by zerkms to copy the specific file you want out of the repository history.

```
svn copy http://server/full/path/to/myPreciousFile.txt@4130 .
```